What was the logic behind the addresses chosen for Atari's F8 banking system?
The Atari 2600 had some big limitations on its cartridges - a maximum size of 4KB (mapped to $1000-$1FFF on the 6507's 8KB address space) and no pin to indicate if the CPU was trying to read or write to an address.
During development of Video Chess, when it seemed like they would need more space, Atari developed a banking scheme for making 8KB cartridges. Reading from $11F8 would set an extra address line latch to 0, selecting the first 4KB of the ROM, while reading from $11F9 would set to it to 1 to select the upper 4KB. This is known today as F8 banking after the first address used.
This scheme requires some duplicate code in both banks, including duplicate start up code since on reset the cart could be set to either bank and that's what leads to my question.
The F8 and F9 addresses are placed just before the 6 byte interrupt vector table expected at the end of memory by a 6502. This makes some general sense. However the 2600 wasn't a generic 6502 system. It was a 6507 which meant that for starters there was no NMI, meaning that FA and FB would've been the highest unused bytes on the cartridge.
But things get even more interesting when you consider FC and FD. These are the reset vector bytes. If the bank switching logic had been wired to them then the cartridge would've had its bank settings reset to a known value on startup (since the CPU reads those two values in a known order), eliminating the need to duplicate the startup code.
So was there a specific reason that F8/F9 was used instead of FC/FD?

Do you have the schematics of such a cartridge or a photo of which chips it contains? Sometimes, the addresses are what they end up being using the simplest or cheapest possible way of doing the address decoding, and if a solution exists which makes bit patterns for 8 and 9 rather than C and D easier then why not use them. Often, some bits are ignored, so the 1FF8 and 1FF9 might just be the first two addresses and there may be others. Or some code or HW was developed on 6502 so FA/FB could not be used. If anyone has a schematic for such a cart the anwer can be analyzed.

@Justme, I agree with your reasoning but prepare yourself for the likelihood of them using PLA-type parts in those days for such a task in high volume. The larger cartridges came along later in the Atari VCS's day. So a schematic alone might not show much.

Reset on the 2600 is a big switch on the front, nestling amongst three to five others; any chance Atari just didn’t want to tie their hands on reaction to a user input? It’s a flimsy suggestion, admittedly.

@TonyM The schematic would show how many address bits goes into it, and which PAL/PLA it is or if it isn't a PAL/PLA but 2 or 3 basic logic chips. Indeed, it could be a PLA.

@Justme: F8-banked cartridges would generally contain a single 24-pin chip with no external circuitry.

@supercat I found pictures of carts with discrete logic ICs, such as 7400 quad NAND, 7486 quad XOR, 7430 eight-input NAND in one of them, 74133 thirteen-input NAND gate in another. I did not work out the schematics but the large NANDs clearly decode the high address bits, XORs can be used to convert the low address bits to highs, and the smaller NAND can be wired as a latch to hold state. May be an earlier cart with more standard ROM instead of all integrated into single chip.

@Justme: I'm unaware of any production Asteroids carts having used anything other than a single chip.  Prototyping carts made for use with a 2764 or 27C64 EPROM would use more circuitry, but if Atari's goal was to have something that could be mass-produced cheaply with discrete logic, I think Atari would have done the bank switching differently.  I've designed an 8K cart using a single 74LS153, 27C64. a resistor, and a timing cap.  Atari's design doesn't minimize chip count, but would have probably been cheap to implement within a mask-ROM chip.

@supercat Your question about ROM suppliers got me looking and I found Atari's original patent for the F8 banking system, US Patent 4,368,515. Of particular interest is figure 6 and the text of pages 7 and 8 which detail the decoding logic of FF8 and FF9, although my understanding of gate arrays is not good enough to pick out a specific reason why these are the "predetermined" addresses that Atari wants (although there are hints that it benefits from the decoding in figure 5). https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/a7/18/2b/dc16ad5357e25d/US4368515.pdf

@David: Interesting.  That patent covers their plans for on-cartridge RAM as well as bank switching, though RAM poses some tricky timing issues that I don't see addressed, at least in the diagrams.

@David, I also found and read the patent a few days ago. As patents should be, it's non-specific on technology to give itself maximum coverage. It covers several broad schemes but not enough to inform what was actually made. Whatever the circuitry actually used was, it has to input all cartridge address lines as it's at byte precision. It wouldn't surprise me if some Atari cartridges used a custom ROM part as some volumes p.a. were enormous by them later years of the paged cartridges. Those huge-vol carts would want costs right down, with sprawling 74xx circuits unlikely (sprawling is >1 IC).

Having done some research, there could be clues why other addresses stated in the question such as FA..FD are avoided but no clear reason why specifically F8/F9 were chosen.
The fact is that the 2600 was first in line and is what it is, with 6507 CPU, which supports no NMI at FA/FB, and the CPU starts directly off from the inserted cartridge ROM that has a maximum address space of 4K bytes. It is unknown what kind of developement environment, if any, it might have had, and early games were small and did not need banking anyway.
After releasing the 2600 in 1977, the 5200 was released in 1983. While it was not compatible with the 2600, it already had a 6502 and supported a whopping 32K bytes for the cartridge ROM. Also an important point is that the CPU did not boot directly from the cart but from internal boot ROM, which eventually searches for a header in cart ROM which defines the start address where to jump in the cart ROM.
Then came the Atari 7800 in 1986, also with internal boot ROM and 6502, and 48K bytes address space for the cartridge, but also it was made backwards compatible with the old 2600 as it was just so popular.
And with the 7800 developement kit it was possible to develop games for both the 2600 and 7800 - the official 600 developement kit was not released yet, if it ever was released at all.
Meanwhile, time has passed, 2600 games have gotten larger, and Atari has had experience over multiple systems and developement environments, and the F8/F9 two bank switching is already mentioned in the dev kit documentation as the method for 2600 and eight banks for the 7800 with addresses F2..F9. So the developement RAM cart had likely the full 48K of RAM and in 2600 mode already supported the F2..F9 bank switching scheme so it can also be used for up to six-bank 2600 ROM developement due to memory mapping reasons (it had to ignore the 2600 non-ROM addresses which loses half of the memory space and as there is then 24K RAM left it's six 4K banks - it is warned that the 7800 developement system was not expressively meant to run in 2600 mode).
Also it is said that when using the developement system as 2600, the address range FF80 to FFF9 must not be used for code as it is used for encryption signature. The dev kit manual also makes clear that at powerup the programmer cannot assume which bank will get control first, so all banks must vector RESET through bank switching code to proper bank.
The devlopement cart contains RAM which can be loaded from a computer so no EEPROM burning is necessary.
The startup ROM code will check if there is a 7800 ROM signature and if not it will read the FFFC/FFFD word to jump execute the 2600 code - so as it's not the CPU itself reading the reset vector, but code copied to RAM checking what addresses $FFFC and $FFFD contain and eventually running JMP $FFFC. So even for this reason, all banks must have identical reset vector.
Also the 7800 developement system has a debugger and the ANTIC chip which uses NMI - so FFFA/FFFB addresses cannot be used either for bank switching.
So basically, in order to be able to run 2600 code and banked 2600 cartridges in developement environments and compatible consoles such as the 7800, the banking system for the 2600 and 7800 were grown similar. The highest 2600 cart addresses that do not interfere with developement environments were $1FF9 and $1FF8, even if a real 2600 system could have used the NMI vector address or even the RESET vector address
Also, for debugging reasons, you might not want the banking hardware to switch to any state just because the CPU reboots, you might specifically want to restart from the last selected bank. On the other hand, the 7800 will always boot to internal ROM which jumps to developement cart ROM instead of computer-uploaded cart RAM.

Using addresses $FFFA/$FFFB or $FFFE or $FFFF could limit the usefulness of the ROM in any future applications that might happen to make use of IRQ or NMI.  While the Atari 2600 didn't do so, I don't think it would have been inconceivable that a future product might be designed so that a store to WSYNC would cause trigger a circuit that would during the next cycle blank the clock during vblank, for the following cycle blank the clock during the left half of the displayed frame, and for the cycle after that blank the clock during the right half of the displayed frame.  This would have eliminated the need for the READY pin, thus allowing use of a small-package 6502 variant which included IRQ or NMI.  If the IRQ or NMI vectors don't hit bank-switch triggers, then each bank can either contain a copy of the code for the interrupt handler, or contain code which records what bank it's in and then switches banks if necessary to execute a common interrupt handler, which can end by switching back to the appropriate bank.  If the vectors hit bank switch triggers, however, there would be no way for the interrupt handler to know which bank it should return to.
Using $FFFC/$FFFD might have made more sense, but would create a somewhat different problem: depending upon the design of the circuitry, an attempt to fetch the reset vector might cause a bank switch to occur sufficiently late in the cycle that the ROM would have insufficient time to read valid data.  Even if addresses $FFFC-$FFFD of bank 1 contain the same data as the corresponding addresses in bank 0, a late bank switch might result in the ROM briefly outputting a pattern that doesn't match either.  If that happened right at the moment when the 6502 was trying to sample the data, it could dispatch execution to the wrong place.
Using $FFF8/$FFF9 may not have been necessary in practice, but it meant that both of these potential issues could be safely ignored.

"What if" questions rarely have a straight answer, but a lot of speculation.
In fact, using $FFFC/FD would also include a lot of speculation, for example that there is no other operation on $FFFC/FD

during reset
between and after reading each byte of the reset vector and
before starting execution of ROM code pointed to by that bytes

Likewise speculation that any later version of the console will do the same.
Going with any non special address is way more safe. No need to think further to save a byte or two.

If a copy of the reset vector and reset code is placed in both banks (as would be necessary when using $1FF8), using $1FFC would have had the advantage of working even if the bank select latch powers up in a metastable state.  I don't know if there's enough info available to make such a question worthwhile, but I'm curious whether Atari invented this bank-switch scheme, or if any mask ROM suppliers supported it earlier?

Most likely, when it was originally designed the 4k window was considered plenty sufficient and adding more address lines would have been expensive.  (This is a common echo for every system design...)
So once they did that, their hands were tied and they had to come out with work arounds like bank switching
As to the F8/F9 addresses, it is very likely that the prototype design used a 6502 instead of a 6507 and there was no benefit to changing the address later or there was a possibility of going back to 6502.
As to the reset vector -- could be just nobody thought of resetting the bank switch on reset, or the reset vector wasn't available for that purpose for some reason or there are ugly race conditions for resetting the back suddenly.

In other words, your guesses are as good as mine in the comments.

None of my guesses are in your comment, or at least, it's not clear to me.  If you want credit, you should answer instead of comment.  For this kind of question, unless you are the original designer, only speculative answers are possible.
